# Convergence of ${\Large\int} _{1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\sqrt{x})\right)^{\alpha}(\cos(x^2)) dx$, for $\alpha \geqslant0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Study the convergence of the following integral for $\alpha \geqslant0$

$${\Large\int} _{1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\sqrt{x})\right)^{\alpha}(\cos(x^2)) dx$$

I have solved it for $\alpha =0$, which is the convergence of $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$, using substitution $t=x^2$ and Dirichlet test. And also for $\alpha\geqslant2$, using Taylor and absolute convergence.
What about $0 \lt \alpha \lt 2$, maybe by the comparision test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the case $\alpha = 0$ we know that $\int_1^\infty \cos(x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x$ exists. Therefore the function $(1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, y \mapsto \int_1^y \cos(x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x \, ,$ is bounded. The function $x \mapsto \left[\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\sqrt{x})\right]^\alpha$ is decreasing on $(1,\infty)$ with limit $0$ for $\alpha >0$ . We can now apply Dirichlet's test again to conclude that the improper Riemann integral converges for every $\alpha > 0$ .

Note that we have absolute convergence if and only if $\alpha > 2$ . For $\alpha = 2$ the integrand is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{|\cos(x^2)|}{x}$ and the integral of this function diverges.

Comment: Thank you, you are right :)